# Undefined Index - Odd Behavior

Tags: php

I have a JSON array I am sorting with PHP. The JSON is sent to the server with AJAX. For some reason, my sort will only work for most of the indexes in my JSON array.

Here is the `class`

```
class FieldSorter {
    public $field;

    function __construct($field) {
        $this->field = $field;
    }

    function sortIt($a, $b) {
        if ($a[$this->field] == $b[$this->field]) return 0;
        return ($a[$this->field] > $b[$this->field]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

A sample* of my JSON would be something similar to

```
record {

        "key": "AAA",
        "default_title": "SOME DEFAULT TITLE",
        "big_stamp": "101515004186",
        "date_stamp": "1015",
        "time_stamp": "15004186",
        "real_title": "SOME TITLE",
        "display_title": "SOME TITLE (3)",
        "display_stamp": "Oct 15th - 3:00:41 pm"
}
```

I can sort by:

- key
- all stamps
- default title

For some reason It shows as undefined index when I search by `real_title` or `display_title` I have verified spelling in all instances.

**EDIT** Error output to console from AJAX

> Notice: Undefined index: display_title

Comment: Make sure all the array elements have those fields.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the exact error message.

Comment: Could you post a sample of the array that is generating this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error implies that some of the array elements are missing some fields, so you need to handle missing data.

```
    function sortIt($a, $b) {
        $field_a = isset($a[$this->field]) ? $a[$this->field] : '';
        $field_b = isset($b[$this->field]) ? $b[$this->field] : '';
        if ($field_a == $field_b) return 0;
        return ($field_a > $field_b) ? 1 : -1;
    }
```

Comment: This solved my issue and actually did point out one record missing those values, thank you for your response. I will add the error above.